# Getting exception message from ASSERT_THROW

Tags: c++, exception, testing, googletest

I'm using `googletest` and in many of my tests I use the `ASSERT_THROW` command. The problem is that if, for example, it throws a different exception than the one I expected, all I get is:

> Actual: it throws a different type.

Is there some way to get it to spit out the return value of `what()` or something?

Comment: Is your exception derived from `std::exception`?  I am looking at the Google Test code, and at one point it catches exceptions derived from `std::exception` and will print `e.what()`.  But I'm still trying ot figure out whether that is part of the `EXPECT_THROW` case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, it is. I tried overriding what() to spit out some different output but to no success. Maybe I wasn't overriding it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably throw by pointer (using `new` keyword)

```
throw new MyDerivedException();
```

and expected to receive a non-pointer type of exception:

```
EXPECT_THROW(blah, MyDerivedException);
```

You should throw by *value*.

```
throw MyDerivedException(); // notice lack of 'new'
```

Comment: Why it's accepted answer? It does not explain how to make Google Test's ASSERT_THROW or EXPECT_THROW to print actual exception type or message. We are still forced to type try/catch while investigating this kind of test failures.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't answer the question and is misleading for someone that comes in with the same question. If i were to ask this question I would be redirected here.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is available in `googletest` since release 1.11 . ( https://github.com/google/googletest/pull/2903 )

Answer (score 0):

A (maybe naive) solution that works for me is to define the following macro:

```
#define ASSERT_THROW_WITH_MESSAGE(code, expected_exception, expected_message) do { \
    try {                                                   \
      { code; }                                             \
      FAIL() << "no exception occured" << endl;             \
    }                                                       \
    catch (const expected_exception &e) {                   \
      EXPECT_THAT(e.what(), testing::HasSubstr(expected_message));   \
    }                                                       \
    catch (const std::exception &e) {                       \
      FAIL() << "an unexpected exception occured: " << e.what() << endl; \
    }                                                       \
    catch (...) {                                           \
      FAIL() << "an unknown exception occured" << endl;     \
    }                                                       \
  } while(0);
```

Answer (score -3):

throw new MyDerivedException() ... EXPECT_THROW(blah, MyDerivedException*);

Comment: Is it a real answer? How it differ from the one above?